# Not able to import matplotlib in spyder

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, spyder

i am new to python, and have installed python version

```
Python 3.7.3
```

pip --version

```
pip 19.1.1 from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

the following are my environment variables

1. pip 19.1.1 from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip
   (python 3.7)
2. C:\Users\lijin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\
3. %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

i have installed matplotlib successfully using the command

```
pip install matplotlib
```

now, while importing matplotlib in the spyder, i am getting an error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.py'

what am i missing here?

Comment: Apparently you installed matplotlib in an environment other than the one spyder is using.

Comment: By using pip to install matplotlib in Anaconda, you most probably broke your Anaconda installation. Now you have to reinstall. For the future, please use conda to install a package, and if it's not found, then you can use pip.